# Stripe Elements not talking to stripe server - No such token: tok_xxxx

Tags: stripe-payments

So I'm migrating from the stripe checkout to elements so that I can register and charge a customer in a single form.
I'm following their documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

Specifically in Step 3 where the token is created with the following code:

```
// Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});
```

The documentation states:

> The handler sends the fields to Stripe for tokenization...

However, it seems nothing is being sent to Stripe at all!

The bottom two requests show the two api calls made using the old checkout: First the card info is sent to /tokens and then my server handles this and makes the /customers request fine.

But when using the elements code nothing seems to be sent to stripe, even though a token is generated and sent to my server. So then I get the 'No such token' error!?

[image: stripe logs]

I can't for the life of me workout why `stripe.createToken(card)` isn't sending the details to their server and yet generates a token?? I've triple checked api keys and everything I can think of. Please help!!

Comment: Typically a 'no such token' error indicates that a publishable key and a secret key being used belong to different accounts. Double check your publishable key and do a hard refresh of your checkout page in case an old publishable key is cached? If that doesn't solve, I'd write into Stripe with this one, they can take a look at your logs and better advise.

Answer (score 0):

What the actual heck... I got it to work but I don't know why this fixed it.

I'm using stripe elements on a .net mvc website and i'm initializing the Stripe class in a view so I can easily pass the key from my viewmodel like so:

```
var stripe = Stripe('@Model.StripePublicKey');
```

Which should work fine, right? No JS errors or anything and it was creating the token, just not posting to stripe's servers....

Anyway, I moved that line into the JS file so it's directly above the other stripe related JS and now it works!?